# Remove whitespace from a string in C#?

Tags: c#

Any one know how to remove *excessive* whitespace from a string?

For example:

```
string myString = "I          am going to work.";
```

Anyone know a good script for doing this kind of trimming?

Comment: the answer seems to be here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/remove-whitespace

Comment: How should a space, followed by a linefeed, and another space be handled?

Comment: @Matt Thats what I get for reading too fast. I saw this and assumed it only handled single spaces. Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ")` would do it.

Comment: Wow nice. I know there's alot of ways of doing this, but this is the shortest one by far. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

`Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " ")` ought to do it.

Comment: I think this will entirely nuke the multiple whitespaces, leading to "Iam going to work." for the given example. I think Regex.Replace(myString, @"\s+", " "); would lead to the right answer.

Comment: Even if you set a minimum, your answer would produce *wrong* results.

Answer (score 1):

I used to have:

```
while (myString.IndexOf("  ") >= 0)
   myString = myString.Replace("  ", " ");
```

Probably there's more elegant way, but it works.

Comment: @jlafay nope, just ordinary spaces.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer using Regular expressions, but this is just another suggestion.

```
string.Join(" ", myString.Split(' ').Where(p => p != string.Empty));
```

Or

```
string.Join(" ", myString.Split(new[] {' '}
               , StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

Good luck!

Comment: ... or maybe use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` with your `string.Split()`? :D

Answer (score -1):

Different methods and which is the fastest if you have 100000 iterations to do.

Code:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        var maxIterations = 100000;

        Console.WriteLine(@"Removing Whitespace from string: "" 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9"" with Total {0}x iterations ", maxIterations);
        Console.WriteLine("\nReplace Operations");
        sw.Start();
        var str = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";

            str = str.Replace(" ", ""); ;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

        sw.Reset();

        //list for and if 
        Console.WriteLine("\nList Operations:");
        sw.Start();
        var str2 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
        var listOfchars = new List<char>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str2 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
            for (int j = 0; j < str2.Length; j++)
            {
                if (!(char.IsWhiteSpace(str2[j])))
                    listOfchars.Add(str2[j]);
            }
            str2 = new string(listOfchars.ToArray());
            listOfchars.Clear();
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str2);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

        sw.Reset();
        //LINQ
        Console.WriteLine("\nLINQ Operations");

        sw.Start();
        var str1 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str1 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
            str1 = String.Concat(str1.Where(c => !Char.IsWhiteSpace(c))); ;
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str1);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");

        //Regex
        sw.Reset();

        Console.WriteLine("\nRegex Operations");

        sw.Start();
        var str3 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxIterations; i++)
        {
            str3 = " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9";
            str3 = Regex.Replace(str3, @"\s+", "");
        }
        sw.Stop();

        Console.WriteLine("Finalstring: " + str3);
        Console.WriteLine("Elapsed time: " + sw.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds + " Milliseconds");
```

Here are the Results:

Removing Whitespace from string: " 1m ir1 11 22 11 a3 bc 9" with Total **100000x iterations**

Replace Operations
Finalstring: 1mir1112211a3bc9
Elapsed time: **12,394 Milliseconds**

List Operations:
Finalstring: 1mir1112211a3bc9
Elapsed time: 29,8071 Milliseconds

LINQ Operations
Finalstring: 1mir1112211a3bc9
Elapsed time: 62,175 Milliseconds

Regex Operations
Finalstring: 1mir1112211a3bc9
Elapsed time: 271,7953 Milliseconds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).