# Remove whitespace in elements in string C#

Tags: c#, split

I have a string which contains multiple items separated by commas :

```cs
 string RESULT =  "D_CA,     P_AMOUNT    ,D_SH,D_CU,D_TO,D_GO,D_LE,D_NU,D_CO,D_MU,D_PMU,D_DP,    P_COMMENT      ";
```

As you can see some elements contain Whitespaces,
My object is to remove all the whitespaces,
This is my code:

```cs
    RESULT.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(p =>
        if (p.Contains(" "))
        {
               RESULT = RESULT.Replace(p, p.Trim());
        }
        });
```

And this is my result:

```
"D_CA,P_AMOUNT,D_SH,D_CU,D_TO,D_GO,D_LE,D_NU,D_CO,D_MU,D_PMU,D_DP,P_COMMENT"
```

it works well, But I ask if there is another more optimized way to get the same result?

Comment: why not a RESULT.Replace(" ","") ?

Comment: var splitResult = RESULT.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Remove whitespace from a string in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526222/remove-whitespace-from-a-string-in-c)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See the [answer by Pavel Anikhouski](http://%20https://stackoverflow.com/a/59679180/732221), which checks the performance of all suggested solutions and actually shows that the simplified LINQ solution does not help performance too much - good to know :-) .

Simpler solution with LINQ:

```
string.Join(string.Empty, input.Where(c=>!char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
```

First we filter away all whitespace characters and then we join them into a string. This has only one string allocation (to create the resulting string) and handles all kinds of whitespace characters, not only spaces.

## Original answer

Use a `StringBuilder` to build up the resulting string and then go through the input string with a `foreach`, always checking `char.IsWhiteSpace(character)`. In case the character is not whitespace, append it in the `StringBuilder` by calling `Append(character)` method. At the end just return the resulting string by calling `ToString()` on the `StringBuilder`.

```
var builder = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var character in input)
{
   if (!char.IsWhiteSpace(character))
   {
      builder.Append(character);
   }
}
return builder.ToString();
```

This implementation is more efficient, as it does not produce any string allocations, except for the end result. It just works with the input string and reads it once.

Comment: Isn't it a bit overkill to use a `StringBuilder` and loops when one can just `Replace()` ?

Comment: Yes whitespace would work, but you would need to list all possible whitespace characters.

Comment: `Regex.Replace(input, @"\s", string.Empty);` should do the job

Comment: Regex is however slower the first time, as it needs to be parsed. I think that would hinder the performance benefit (although worth a benchmark :-) )

Comment: Performance vs readibility... Would be nice to benchmark your linq solution vs a RegEx one

Comment: As the OP asked for optimized solution, I suppose the performance is primary concern. But agreed regex and LINQ solutions are more readable than the one I posted originally :-D

Comment: Actually, regex is 10 times slower, that solution using stringbuilder. Extension method from my answer above is about 30-40% slower, the solution here. That's about performance :)

Answer (score 8):

I suppose you need the string with whitespaces removed. You could use [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=netframework-4.8)

```
RESULT = RESULT.Replace(" ",string.Empty);
```

Alternatively, you could also use Regex for replace,

```
RESULT = Regex.Replace(RESULT,@"\s",string.Empty);
```

The regex approach would ensure replacement of all whitespace characters including tab,space etc

Answer (score 7):

Isn't what you looking for?

```
var noWhiteSpaces = RESULT.Replace(" ", string.Empty);
```

Comment: This works with spaces only, not general whitespace characters.

Answer (score 5):

You can `Trim()`:

```
var split = RESULT.Split(new[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .Select(s=> s.Trim());
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use the following extension method for that

```cs
public static class Ext
{
    public static string RemoveWhitespaces(this string input)
    {
        return new string(input.ToCharArray()
            .Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
            .ToArray());
    }
}
```

Usage sample

```cs
string RESULT = "D_CA,     P_AMOUNT    ,D_SH,D_CU,D_TO,D_GO,D_LE,D_NU,D_CO,D_MU,D_PMU,D_DP,    P_COMMENT      ";
RESULT = RESULT.RemoveWhitespaces();
```

`Char.IsWhiteSpace` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.iswhitespace?view=netframework-4.8#remarks) indicates all Unicode whitespace characters.

There is a simple benchmark for all proposed solutions below. In terms of performance the usual `Replace` is fastest method, but it doesn't remove all whitespace characters. The solution with `StringBuilder` seems most relevant in terms of performance and functionality, it's about 2 times faster than extension above.  The `Regex` and `Linq` solution are few times slower than other ones

[image]

Comment: @MartinZikmund thank you, I've added a string builder result as well

Comment: Could you check the LINQ solution too, please :-) ?

Comment: @MartinZikmund I've added details, `Linq` solution is expensive as well, but faster than regex

Answer (score 3):

You can simplify the code like this:

```
RESULT.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

Assuming that you need the elements in an Enumerable. Otherwise just the Replace() should work for you.

Answer (score 1):

I can only to add that you can put the linq into the static method

```
public static class Utility
{
    public static string RemoveWhitespaces(this string input)
    {
        return string.Join(string.Empty, input.Where(c => !char.IsWhiteSpace(c)));
    }
}
```

and then use it with any your string:

```
Console.WriteLine("asdas asdas sa   asdasd232 sd".RemoveWhitespaces());
```

Answer (score -1):

RESULT.Replace(" ", string.Empty);

Answer (score -2):

You can use .Trim() to make a new string without any whitespaces.

```
string x = "Hello World";
console.writeline(x.Trim());
//Output : "HelloWorld"
```

you can check other overloads of string.Trim() here:
[String.Trim Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.trim?view=netframework-4.8)

Comment: The very link you provided clearly states  
`Trim()` _Removes all **leading and trailing** white-space characters from the current string._ The output of your code is "Hello World".....

Comment: Try it yourself!